# Gatling Evaluate Expression Language

Tags: scala, gatling

> Gatling parses Strings parameter values and turn them into functions that will compute a result based on the data stored into the Session when they will be evaluated.

[Gatling Documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/expression_el/)

Is there any way to do this manually in an exec?

I have multiple request body templates which use EL attributes, the request sent will differ based on a feeder

The code I currently have is as such:

```java
// Body itself contains attributes say ${uuid}
val body1 = Source.fromResource("body1.json")
val body2 = Source.fromResource("body2.json")

val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Dynamic body")
    .feed(feeder)
    .exec(session => {
      if(session("requestType").as[String].equals("first"))
        session.set("request", body1)
      else 
        session.set("request", body2)
      session
    }
    .exec(http("Http Call")
      .post(url)
      .body(StringBody("${request}")) 
// This won't evaluate the nested attribute and body will remain ${uuid} instead of an actual UUID
    )
```

I expect that there won't be a way to evaluate nested EL attributes, but is there a way to manually evaluate it using session variables? Something along the lines of

```java
.exec(session => {
    val evaluatedBody = merge(body1, session)
    session("request", evaluatedBody)
    session
})
```

I've seen ELCompiler being referenced in some other questions, but not sure where to import it from and how to use it with session values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`ElFileBody`](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/request/#request-body) that takes a file path parameter, which can be a function.

```scala
val scn = scenario("Dynamic body")
    .feed(feeder)
    .exec(http("Http Call")
      .post(url)
      .body(
        ElFileBody(session =>
            session("requestType").as[String] match {
              case "first" => "body1.json"
              case _       => "body2.json"
            }
        )
      )
    )
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, although would be great if you could also add how to do the same if the input was a variable string(containing attributes) instead of a file

Comment: @IsaacN Exactly, I need the version with a string so much right now.

Comment: @Taserface This won't happen. We will never parser recursively because we only want to parse statically one boot, not dynamically at runtime. Functions and session API are the way for more complex use cases.