# Nested attributes in Gatling Expression Language

Tags: java, performance-testing, gatling

I use Gatling Java  to write a performance test.
I have a session variable 'VAR_X' with a value of 'Jerry'.

My code has a 'post()' method that sends a request. It uses a custom feeder to provide a body for the request.

```
public ChainBuilder post() {
    List<String> requestBodyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Map<String, Object>> feeder =requestBodyList.add(Collections.singletonMap("REQUEST_BODY", (Object) "my_config { x: #{VAR_X} }")).iterator();
    return feed(feeder)
        .exec(http("Post request"))
        .post("x_resource/")
        .body(StringBody("#{REQUEST_BODY}"))
}
```

Currently my code results in the request body to be "my_config { x: #{VAR_X} }".
I would like the value of session variable 'VAR_X' to get inserted into the request body, by using Gatling Expression Language (GEL).
The desired request body should be:
"my_config { x: Jerry }"

How can I change my code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Gatling Expression Language is intended as a simple solution for simple use cases.

For more complex use cases, you have to switch to using [functions](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/function/) and the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/session_api/#fetching-data).

Comment: Okay, can you please provide me with an example how can I achieve this? To me, Gatling lacks a few functionalities as the one above to be flexible and achieve complex (but at the same time, quite common) things easily. The documentation also has very little examples on those.

Comment: You have an example in the other ticket you commented on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68085836/5269205